# DiGMap WFS doesn't work on GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

I'm trying to publish one of our customer Web Feature Services in Geoserver 2.19.0 and I'm getting error when I publish it. As per the customer, their WFS service is compliant to OGC standard and it can easily publish it in QGIS. So, I'm trying to figure out why this WFS service is working in QGIS and but not in Geoserver!

The following is the DigMap WFS URL covering the whole of the United Kingdom, which is also in OGC format. This DigMap service has the same schema as the one provided by the customer. This DigMap service URL is also viewed in QGIS but not in GeoServer 2.19;

http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/digmap625k_gsml_cgi_gs/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&AcceptVersions=2.0.0

[image]

Why doesn't this WFS service work on GeoServer?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. For comparing using this (GeoServer supplied WFS) between QGIS and GeoServer.  Are just saying that the features show in QGIS to indicate that service is valid, but then trying to cascade the WFS, in your version of GeoServer and that isn't working.  Sorry it isn't clear

Comment: it looks like the inspire schema is not declared properly in the WFS response, you probably need to talk to the server owner

Comment: @IanTurton what schema declaration is expected by GeoServer here to allow the cascading of the 2.0.0 service.  Version 1.1.0.  seems to cascade OK.  The Capabilities response is valid according to oXygen.  I'm not the author of the service but know who  is.

Comment: @IanTurton -  is there any INSPIRE xsd schema declaration tutorial available for GeoServer? So that I can explain to the customer about the changes required for the their service.

Comment: @IanTurton - Is this tutorial the right one for GeoServer? https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/documents/Network_Services/Technical_Guidance_View_Services_v2.12.pdf

Comment: No idea, but I doubt it - I don't think that this WFS has simple features so it probably can't be cascaded in GeoServer. The features are all (mostly) in GeoSciMl not plain GML as GeoServer expects

Comment: Are you just using the BGS service as an example of a GeoServer WFS service that works?  If not are you saying that BGS is your customer, or somehow related to your customer.

Comment: yeah, BGS is not our customer. Since the customer meta metadata definition is identical to BGC WFS, I am using the BGC service as an example.

Comment: Your title is very misleading then, and not a summary of the issue.  Which would actually appear to be how to set up an INSPIRE download service using GeoServer.

Comment: @nmtoken - In fact, I am unfamiliar with the INSPIRE extension. This is the first time I have heard of this extension. Do you think the INSPIRE extension can resolve their service schema issue?

Comment: The INSPIRE plugin for GeoServer exists to add the required extended capabilities to a WMS or WFS, it doesn't help you map your data to a format suitable for providing INSPIRE data.  For that you'll need the 'app-schema plugin' (the old way of doing it) or possibly the newer Features-Templating Extension.

Comment: Which issue? Your question is very unclear. If your customer has a WFS that works on QGIS (one assumes QGIS server because WFS needs some server software) then why would they want to cascade or serve through GeoServer? Is it instead that your customer has some GML, and wants to be able to provide it as a WFS?

Comment: The client has had their own WFS for a long time and uses QGIS to see the layers. Now, they want to use the same service data via GeoServer for a web-based system. I'm using BGS as a test service because their both services are almost the same schema definition.

Comment: You should change the title and the body of the question to reflect your clarifying comments.  I'm still not understanding though if they have an existing WFS why they can't use that for a web based system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure an INSPIRE compliant WFS using GeoServer such as the DiGMap WFS example, you will need the `app-schema plugin` to map your data model to the appropriate INSPIRE data model.

A good description of the process can be found in the OneGeology cookbook [How To Serve a GeoSciML Version 4.0 Web Feature
Service (WFS) Using GeoServer](https://onegeology.org/archive/docs/technical/OneGeologyWFSCookbook_v1.3.pdf)

Additionally, you will need the INSPIRE plugin to add an extended capabilities section to the WFS GetCapabilities.